# SQL how to compare using a char

Tags: sql

I want to get all names starting with a specific character.

Example:

```
char = 'C'
```

**names:**
Chal,
Chess,
Arter,
Bain,Dave

**Result:** Chal, Chess

Comment: SELECT name FROM yourTable WHERE name LIKE 'C%'

Comment: Sorry dude, but this kind of questions will get you downvotes only. I did not downvote but I would suggest you read through W3 schools before posting a question like this.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases `LIKE` is what you need. An SQL Server example would be:

```
SELECT Name
FROM   Names
WHERE  Name LIKE 'C%'
```

This should work in `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `Oracle` and `PostGress`.

You should state your Database engine for more proper answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` in `where` clause, eg:

```
WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'C%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like "C%";
```